# angular watch for angular-leaflet-directive

Tags: angularjs, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I am trying to place `$watch` on a value in angular to setup controls differently depending on instructions from the controller and I have tried to follow the lead in [angular-leaflet-directive](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive/blob/master/src/directives/center.js#L107) using `leafletScope.$watch("variable")`.

I have added a new `$watch` with equality comparison as it's an object:

```
leafletScope.$watch("controls", function(controlOpts) {...}, true)
```

I then call it in the controller using:

```
angular.extend($scope, {
    controls: {}
}
```

This is to initialise the controls as this seems to be required.

I then call it later on an event using:

```
$scope.controls = { new object }
```

If I log the change in controls and then also on the $watch event, I get the following sequence:

- control `$watch` event logged
- `$scope.control` change event logged
- no further logs

The fact that the watch isn't called after the `$scope` is changed suggests I am doing this wrong.

Can anyone advise me where, or if I have reached the wrong conclusion in my simple test.

If I do the same and change my "center" model, I get:

- center`$watch` event logged
- `$scope.center` change event logged
- center`$watch` event logged with new value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a clash between angular-leaflet-directive and the html minifier I was using [html-minifier](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference). The angular-leaflet-directive notation for leaflet controls is `controls` so in my html file I had

```
<leaflet center="centre" controls="controls" layers="layers" width="1200px" height="800px"></leaflet>
```

the html-minifier took controls="controls" to be a boolean attribute and with the [collapse boolean attributes](http://perfectionkills.com/experimenting-with-html-minifier/#collapse_boolean_attributes) flag on reduced it to

```
<leaflet center="centre" controls layers="layers" width="1200px" height="800px"></leaflet>
```

Which wasn't good. I will request this is either better documented in angular-leaflet-directive or they change the name of controls to leaflet-controls or something to avoid this happening to unsuspecting folk like me in the future.

Incidently the true flag on the watch proved to be too resource intensive and I removed it and it still worked..